# Headphones for big head?

Tags: headphones

For a family member with quite a big head, I'm looking for a headphone to replace the one which is (kinda) broken. Naturally I'm looking for a replacement which will do better, so I'm asking here for recommendations.

Object searched: **Headphone**

**Mandatory requirements:**

- 3.5mm jack input
- Must be closed design
- Impedance must be between 40 and 80 Ohm
- Cable must either be removable from the actual headphone or be at least 1.5m
- Must be able to accomodate the following "head specs":

  - (Full) Ear diameter: 8cm (from bottom to top of the ear)
  - Head diameter: 15cm (from ear-to-ear)
  - Height: 13cm (from mid of ear, straight ob the top of the head)
  - Perimeter length (?): 37cm (from the middle of the ear over the top of the head to the other ear)
- Price must be less than 150€